# Convert number to a letter using a modulus

Tags: r

Using letters[1:26] with a modulus 5, for a check character in a personal identification number creates "character (0)" which should be an "E". Is there a way to get around this? This a slimmed down the version but the principle is the same.

I can generate a list of character vectors but the zero from the modulus creates a dropout for "11E".

```
PIN <- c("08A","07D","10C","11E", "10C")
DATA <- data.frame(PIN)
DATA %>% mutate(PIN = as.character(PIN)) -> DATA

LETTERS[(as.numeric(substr(DATA$PIN, start = 2, stop = 2)) * 7 +
         as.numeric(substr(DATA$PIN, start = 1, stop = 1)) * 8 ) %% 5]
```

Generates

```
[Output1] "A" "D" "C" "C"
```

In the end, I want to run it back against the check alpha character to valid the number.

```
substr(DATA$PIN, start = 3, stop = 3)
[Output2] "A" "D" "C" "E" "C"
```

The dropout disrupts the sequence and causes misalignments

```
[Output1] == [Output2]
[1]  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: The rule for your checksum is unclear, since the computation mod 5 that you’re performing by definition generates a number inside the range [0, 5[, i.e. including 0 and excluding 5. Using the result of this to subset into a vector in R doesn’t make sense because vector indices in R are 1-based not 0-based. But adding +1 to your result doesn’t seem to be what you want because then all checksum characters would be shifted. So what’s the *exact* rule for generating the checksum character? It can’t be what you’ve described.

Comment: The format of the PIN is seven digits plus a check character. A second character may be used. ( 1234567A or 1234567AZ)

Comment: In reverse order, each digit is multiplied by a weight, 2, 3, and so on until the first digit is multiplied by 8. Add up each result. Divide by 23 and the remainder (modulus 23) will indicate the character position on the alphabet.

Comment: Thus the PIN 1234567 will be calculated as the sum of 7*2, 6*3, 5*4, 4*5, 3*6, 2*7 and 1*8. This 112 when divided by 23 leaves a remainder of 20. The twentieth letter of the English alphabet is ‘T’. The correct PIN is therefore 1234567T. Where the remainder is zero, the check letter is W.

A weighting of 9 will be assigned to the numeric equivalent of the alphabetic character in position 9.

Accordingly, the check character for the “old” number 1234567 is “T”, whereas the check character for the “new” number 1234567_A will be “F”.

Answer (score 0):

One of them is giving 0 value with `%%`.  Not clear about the conditions, but we can correct with an `ifelse`

```
i1 <-  (as.numeric(substr(DATA$PIN, start = 2, stop = 2)) * 7 +
       as.numeric(substr(DATA$PIN, start = 1, stop = 1)) * 8 ) %% 5
LETTERS[ifelse(i1 == 0, max(i1) + 1, i1)]
#[1] "A" "D" "C" "E" "C"
```

Comment: if I get to z which is 26 + 1 then it produces a NA

Comment: the full problem uses a modulus 23 and seven digits with one or two alpha check characters from A to Z